# What is the difference between "hill climbing" and "greedy" algorithms?

Tags: algorithm

Please explain the difference between "hill climbing" and "greedy" algorithms.

It seems both are similiar, and I have a doubts that "hill climbing" is an algorithm; it seems to be an optimization. Is this correct?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Hill-climbing and greedy algorithms are both heuristics that can be used for optimization problems. In an **optimization problem**, we generally seek some optimum combination or ordering of problem elements. A given combination or ordering is a solution. In either case, a solution can evaluated to compare it against other solutions.

In a **hill-climbing** heuristic, you start with an initial solution. Generate one or more neighboring solutions. Pick the best and continue until there are no better neighboring solutions. This will generally yield one solution. In hill-climbing, we need to know how to evaluate a solution, and how to generate a "neighbor."

In a **greedy** heuristic, we need to know something special about the problem at hand. A greedy algorithm uses information to produce a single solution.

A good **example** of an optimization problem is a 0-1 knapsack. In this problem, there is a knapsack with a certain weight limit, and a bunch of items to put in the knapsack. Each item has a weight and a value. The object is to maximize the value of the objects in the knapsack while keeping the weight under the limit.

A greedy algorithm would pick objects of highest density and put them in until the knapsack is full. For example, compared to a brick, a diamond has a high value and a small weight, so we would put the diamond in first.

Here is an example of where a greedy algorithm would fail: say you have a knapsack with capacity 100. You have the following items:

- Diamond, value 1000, weight 90 (density = 11.1)
- 5 gold coins, value 210, weight 20 (density each = 10.5)

The greedy algorithm would put in the diamond and then be done, giving a value of 1000. But the optimal solution would be to include the 5 gold coins, giving value 1050.

The hill-climbing algorithm would generate an initial solution--just randomly choose some items (ensure they are under the weight limit). Then evaluate the solution--that is, determine the value. Generate a neighboring solution. For example, try exchanging one item for another (ensure you are still under the weight limit). If this has a higher value, use this selection and start over.

Hill climbing is not a greedy algorithm.

Comment: Your conclusion sounds misleading. The specific greedy algorithm you described constructs the solution greedily, while the hill climbing heuristic reaches a local optima greedily. The only difference is that the greedy step in the first one involves constructing a solution while the greedy step in hill climbing involves selecting a neighbour (greedy local search). Hill climbing is a greedy heuristic. If you want to distinguish an algorithm from a heuristic, I would suggest reading Mikola's answer, which is more precise.

Answer (score 7):

Yes you are correct. Hill climbing is a general mathematical optimization technique (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing). A greedy algorithm is any algorithm that simply picks the best choice it sees at the time and takes it.

An example of this is making change while minimizing the number of coins (at least with USD). You take the most of the highest denomination of coin, then the most of the next highest, until you reach the amount needed.

In this way, hill climbing **is** a greedy algorithm.